# Xcopy creates blank/empty csv files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a batch file that I use (and have used all day successfully) to copy some badly named files (all are 1.csv) in a horrendously long dir tree to a different location with a more appropriate name (and shorter route to the file).  It suddenly quit working; specifically, it IS making the new directory and it IS making the file with the correct name; however, the 'new' file is basically void.  The source file may be 26mb but the destination file created is 287k. I'm using

```
xcopy "Z:\jobs\!q-z\clientname\tars\2016_06_06\home\abcd\xyz\qwert\more\moarr\deeper\deepest\x\y\z\1.csv" "Z:\jobs\!q-z\clientname\daily\160606\biz.csv*"
```

As I said earlier, this was working just fine all day long and suddenly began creating all dest files exactly the same size, which is an empty shell of a csv file.  I have a feeling this might have to do with some sort of "cache" issue, but if so, I don't know how to clear it.  Or is there some error in my syntax that allowed it to work almost accidentally before today?  I've tried using pretty much every switch for xcopy, with no better results.

Also, the only thing that ever changes in the batch file is the date.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Make sure you haven't run out disk space.

Comment: I have 600 gigs available space; the file sizes total 25 to 30 megs for all 6 files that I'm copying (combined).  Source & destination drive are the same.